# An Alternative to OFFSET... FETCH NEXT in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `posts` table in SQL Server and I need to select (say) the first 10 rows ordered by the count of their upvotes, here is the DB script:

```
create database someforum
go
use someforum
go

create table users (
user_id int identity primary key,
username varchar(80) unique not null
);

create table posts (
post_id int identity primary key,
post_time datetime,
post_title nvarchar(32),
post_body nvarchar(255),
post_user int foreign key references users(user_id)
);

create table votes (
vote_id int identity primary key,
user_id int foreign key references users(user_id),
vote_type bit, --upvote=true downvote=false
post_id int foreign key references posts(post_id)
);

insert into users values ('foo'),('bar')
insert into posts values
(getdate(),N'a post by foo',N'hey',1),
(getdate(),N'a post by bar',N'hey!',2)
insert into votes values (1,0,1),(2,0,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,2) --first post downvoted by its poster (foo) and bar, second post was upvoted by both users
```

I need an efficient query to select the next top 10 rows from Posts based on count of upvotes. How can I achieve this in SQL Server 2008?

**Important edit:** I stupidly forgot to mention that I was using SQL Server 2008 R2 to which `OFFSET... FETCH NEXT` wasn't introduced yet. I also edited out what is currently irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: have you ever tried something? seems like you only want us to do all these for you.

Comment: question 1 hint: `ORDER BY DESCENDING`, `GROUP BY post_id, type`, `COUNT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I wanted (without using the `score` column):

```
select top 10 p.post_title,sum(case when vote_type=1 then 1 else -1 end) as score
from posts p join votes v on p.post_id = v.post_id
group by p.post_title
```

And as to the alternative to `OFFSET… FETCH NEXT`, I found a great solution in [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/136259/offset-fetch-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

1. There *is* no "best"; but a *working* command might involve `select top 10 ... order by Score desc`. I realize that your `posts` tables doesn't ***have*** a `Score` column (that aggregates and denormalizes the votes), but: you can change that
2. the [`OFFSET` / `FETCH` clause](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I edited the "best" because it's not the "best" word to use. I didn't add a Score column because it's calculable I guess? so if I added a Score column should I create a trigger to update it each time a new vote is added?

Comment: @Outman just because something is calculable doesn't mean you shouldn't store it - especially if performance is a concern; if a trigger works for you: sure, have fun

Answer (score 0):

You could use a gridView object to display the results: this will allow users to sort on various columns with the minimum of code on your part and also allow pagination, the inclusion of numbered links at the bottom of the gridView allowing users to move through the list of results.

Using a gridView with 10 rows will allow the display of your top 10 and users will also have the option of moving through the rest of the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can calcucalte and filter by this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(*) as upvotes FROM posts AS p INNER JOIN votes AS v ON (p.post_id = v.post_id) WHERE v.type = true
) as v_post  OFFSET 10 ROWS
```

2) You can shift post by step count (10 at now) in the end of query: `FETCH NEXT 10`, `FETCH NEXT 20` etc.

Comment: Since this is SQL-Server, `LIMIT` should probably be `OFFSET`/`FETCH NEXT`